# Angular7 dev environment module constructor not running

Tags: angular

I have inherited an existing Angular7 codebase.

One of the modules contain some initialization code in it's constructor like so:

```
@NgModule({...})
export class SomeModule {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

The problem I'm running into is, the constructor is not getting called in dev environment when run with `ng serve`. But, if I run with `ng serve --prod`, the code is called and everything works fine.

Can someone please point me to the problem? I've tried almost everything but nothing seems to work.

**EDIT**

Contents of `angular.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "projectName": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "spec": false,
          "inlineTemplate": false,
          "viewEncapsulation": "None",
          "prefix": "",
          "styleext": "scss",
          "changeDetection": "OnPush"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "spec": false,
          "prefix": "",
          "changeDetection": "OnPush"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:service": {
          "spec": false
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/scss/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "commonChunk": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "serviceWorker": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "projectName:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "projectName:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "projectName:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
              },
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "projectName-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "projectName:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "projectName"
}
```

Contents of `environment.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false
};
```

Contents of `environment.prod.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

**EDIT**
I enabled AOT and now the project runs fine in dev environment.

Comment: Please append your question to include the contents of `angular.json` and the files within `/src/app/environments/`

Comment: @NathanBeck I've updated the question with the requested files.

Comment: Use your ide to search for `environment.production`

Comment: @AndrewAllen I meant to say that the contents of environment.ts and environment.prod.ts was never changed. I have included the files in the question.

Comment: @Trinopoty I know...you’re looking for something like `environment.production
      ? []: Somemodule`...hence look for `environment.production`

Comment: That all looks fine. The `--prod` flag will serve the app with AOT compilation and tree shaking, so it's not surprising the constructor code is hit with `--prod`. Is there any condition in `main.ts` that mentions `environment.production`? Where is the module in question declared, was the file a recent addition?

Comment: I agree with @AndrewAllen -- see if anything interesting pops up with a global search on `environment.production`

Comment: I found `NgxsModule.forRoot([], {developmentMode: !environment.production}),` in AppModule, don't really have anything else interesting.

Comment: @NathanBeck `main.ts` contains the standard `enableProdMode();` behind a `environment.production` check.

Comment: Last thought before I head out is a bit of a shot in the dark as everything you've shown looks solid -- is this module loaded in `AppModule` and then lazy loaded somewhere else?

Comment: @NathanBeck Yes. It's a lazy loaded module from `app-routing.module.ts`.